# When importing tag, GIT downloads again full commit history

Tags: git, git-svn

We have an SVN repository with almost 190k commits. Locally I have created a GIT repository in order to work more comfortably.

When I have to update my local GIT repository and fetch the new commits to the SVN repository, I use this combination of commands:

`!git svn fetch && git svn rebase -l && git push . remotes/trunk:master && git push -f origin master`

(found here: https://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2010/11/29/git-svn-aliases-git-up-and-git-dci/)

Everything works smoothly, except when someone created a tag in the SVN repository: in that case git-svn will download full history for that tag (from revision 1 to the last one), which means that the sync, instead of taking a couple of minutes, will take 10-15 hours.

Could all this be avoided? Maybe the command I'm using is not the right one?

Thanks!

Comment: git and subversion tags are substantially different. As far as I know - you cannot avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch multiple branches/tags from SVN then, by default, `git svn` tries to connect these to the last common ancestor. Finding this ancestor can be very expensive -- sometimes `git svn` will reread the complete history of the repository.

On the other hand your alias seems to be concerned only about `trunk` ignoring any tags and branches. Given this situation you have several options with varying consequences:

1. Setup your git repository for *exactly* *one* branch. Do *not* use the options `-s` or `--stdlayout`. Obviously you will only sync a certain part of the SVN repo.
2. Use the option [`--no-follow-parent`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn---follow-parent) (and look at the section [Handling of SVN branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_handling_of_svn_branches) for more explanation). In this case you can track multiple branches/tags but the history of a new tag/branch will not be connected to its ancestor.
3. In some situations `git svn` tries to reread the history from r0 up to HEAD. It does so with 100 revisions per chunk which can be very slow for large/old repos. In this case you can try to speed things up using the option `--log-window-size=3000` for `git svn fetch` (See [doc here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn---log-window-sizeltngt)).